# Zero-downtime pod eviction for single replica deployment

Tags: kubernetes

My app runs as a deployment with 1 replica.

When I'm executing `kubectl rollout restart deployment my-app`, it starts new pod first, waits for it to become ready and then deletes old pod. That provides zero-downtime restart, while keeping single replica.

However when something (like cluster-autoscaler or node drain) decides to evict a pod from the node, it deletes pod immediately. The new pod is scheduled on the new node, however it takes some time to pull an image, start the container, initialize the app. During this time, there's a downtime.

The question is: is it possible to somehow achieve zero-downtime restarts when pod is being evicted from the node? I expect it to work similarly to rollout restart: start new pod on a different node, wait for it to become ready and then delete the evicted pod.

Comment: what does the pod do? in case of an web page you could serve stale content

Comment: @djdomi There are different pods, mostly web applications or backend services. I don't way to pay price for true HA running services in 2+ replicas (rare downtime in case of hardware failure is acceptable), however having downtime because of events like cluster scaling which occurs more often is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, achieving zero-downtime restarts for a single-replica deployment evicted due to external factors like autoscalers or node drains is not directly possible within vanilla Kubernetes. These evictions usually happen abruptly, leaving no room for coordinated transitions like in `kubectl rollout restart`.

However, there are several workarounds to minimize downtime and approach near-zero downtime like:

- Using PodDisruptionBudgets (PDBs)
- Implementing PreStop Hooks
- Configuring proper liveness and readiness probes for your pod

When a pod is evicted from a node, it is immediately deleted, and the new pod is scheduled on a different node. However, it takes some time to pull an image, start the container, and initialize the app, resulting in downtime. To achieve zero-downtime restarts when a pod is being evicted from the node, it is recommended to use a Deployment instead of a single replica deployment.

To know more about how to achieve zero-downtime application with Kubernetes, see this [link](https://www.qovery.com/blog/how-to-achieve-zero-downtime-application-with-kubernetes/).